# How do you remove the new test progress bar from Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

This progress bar has just been added to Visual Studio 2022.  In the picture, it starts with the text "Test run finished: 5 Tests...":

[image]

How do you remove this?  It's eating into the already limited space available below (which is where the tests are listed it out), it's at least somewhat redundant with other status bars, and I don't like to adjust window sizes and such to custom values outside of their defaults.

Comment: Does Options->Test->General->Logging Level (scroll down to find it) have any effect? (Just guessing, as I don't have any valid tests set up ATM.)

Comment: @AdrianMole Unfortunately not apparently.